# Using JSR-354 ExchangeRates prevents application from exiting

Tags: java-money, jsr354

I'm trying to use JavaMoney 1.0 in my application and noticed that when using default `ExchangeRateProvider`s, some threads will still be running when my application finishes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MonetaryConversions.getExchangeRateProvider("IMF");
}
```

I'm aware that provided `ExchangeRateProvider`s are, by default, configured to regularly fetch rates but it seems that there is a deadlock somewhere or that the thread(s) are not marked as daemons.

Or maybe there is a way to shutdown `ExchangeRateProvider`s that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. Bumping JavaMoney to version 1.1 solved the problem for me.